# is it possible to loop though 2 values using only 1 loop?

Tags: while-loop, f#, mutable

I have mutable variables x and y, and I can only use a while (something) loop. I want to loop through 0 .. 9 and 0 .. 9. I have made many attempts using different if statements and in different orders. Here's what I have so far.

```
open System

let mutable x = 0
let mutable y = 0

let n = 9

while x <> n && y <> n do
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y)
    printf "."

    // ...

Console.Read() |> ignore
```

Comment: This sounds like an assignment that you're supposed to solve yourself. If you can be more specific about what you have difficulty with we might be able to help you along. But we're not going to just give you the solution, since that would defeat the point of the exercise.

Comment: @glennsl It's not an assignment I'm not in studying yet, I just worded that way to try and convey what I'm trying to do better. I want to end up with a square of "." that is 10x10 on the console. I tried adding a third variable i which will determine if I should loop through x or y now but still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way of doing this would be to use two nested loops - if you're iterating over a known number of items (rather than unboundedly, until some condition holds), then `for` loop is easier:

```
for x in 0 .. 9 do
  for y in 0 .. 9 do
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y)
    printf "."
```

The nested loop iterates 10 times and the outer loop runs the nested one 10 times, so you get 100 executions of the nested body.

You could do this with just one loop if you iterate over 100 values, i.e. `0 .. 10*10-1` which is `0 .. 99`. If you have numbers from `0` to `99`, you can then calculate `x` and `y` by taking `x=n/10` and `y=n%10`:

```
for n in 0 .. 10 * 10 - 1 do
  let x = n / 10
  let y = n % 10
  Console.SetCursorPosition(20+x, y)
  printf "."
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for, I was just thinking I'd probably have to inculde the maximum number of iterations in there and use the modulus somewhere. Thanks! Now I can compare speeds (not that I'm expecting it to be faster than nested loops).

Comment: The bottleneck in this case will be the console activity; I dare say the kind of loop you use (single loop, nested loop, hand-rolled recursive function, or even a sequence) should not make a significant difference.